# What are the GC implications of having a large array of small classes?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection

If I have a multidimensional array with many hundreds of thousands of entries and all entries are class objects that are long-lived (ie are only created once and live for the entire duration of  the application), are there any GC implications I need to consider? Will this affect how much time it takes the GC to complete? Will this affect future allocations/deallocations?

For context, I am trying to make a decision between using a large array of classes or a large array of structs.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - e.g. in considering using classes vs structs, what are your arguments or dilemma in one vs the other?  You're talking about future allocations, but you said lifetime is duration of application, so it applies no future reallocations of the array.

Comment: @LB2 The main feature of my question is the GC implications of a large array of small classes. The context I provided was just ancillary information that you don't really need. I've found via profiling that my algorithm works better on a large array of classes instead of structs and want to make sure I am not overlooking something. The allocations statement applied to new allocations in general; not ones specific to the large array of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those small classes are are long lived, they will soon be promoted to Gen2 objects and will not affect Gen0 and Gen1 collection. They will not affect allocation. They will affect Gen2 collection though, but if GC is doing Gen2 collection, then you have a different problem. You are running out of memory.

In addition to affecting GC, class vs struct will affect memory layout of you objects though. This will affect CPU cache performance which may have a larger impact on performance.

Comment: This is useful, thanks. I've found thus far via profiling that the large array of classes tends to run ~20% faster due to elimination of struct copy overhead in my use case. I was mostly concerned about hidden performance hits that I wasn't measuring. Going to leave this question open a bit longer before accepting.

Answer (score 1):

A large enough object is allocated in [Large Object Heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) (LOH) that does not get collected in the same way as regular heap allocations.  Objects in LOH do not get compacted normally, so it is much easier to wind up with fragmented memory, and, therefore, much likelier to get `OutOfMemoryException` even though your process is not using much of memory at all (my experience a while back was 700MB on a 32bit process could fairly easily run into such condition when dealing with a lot of large objects).

The reason I was asking about future allocations is that if this is the only large object that you expect in your program and it is not frequently reallocated along with others, then having one or a few is probably not a big deal and unlikely to affect you too much.  It's OK to have large objects such as massive arrays, or big strings.  If allocations requiring LOH would be frequent enough, then it may be a concern.

Struct vs objects.  Objects obviously make the width of an array the same size as the pointer - i.e. 32 or 64 bits.  Structs can be stored as the value itself in array, so if the struct is larger, then array of the same size element-wise would be larger byte-wise.  Hence smaller number of elements will cause array to be allocated into LOH.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I found it useful. The array will be allocated once and never again and live forever.